# Is there an SDK for VMware fusion?

Tags: vmware-fusion, sdk

Is anyone aware of and SDK for VMware Fusion?

I'd like to be able to programmatically control fusion from inside of a java/scala application.   The closest thing I have found is the vmrun CLI command but it doesn't have all the features and I'd rather not be shelling out to console to run commands if and SDK exists.

Edit:  I'd like to be able to do this directly from MacOSX without requiring a Windows VM.   So a java based app controling a fusion instance locally.

Comment: http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can for Fusion. Enterprise features == enterprise money. If you need this, you will probably need to look at vSphere.